# zsh: command not found: mongo on MacOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-catalina

I installed mongodb on Mac using Homebrew and started the daemon.

```
% brew services list
Name                  Status  User Plist
mongodb-community@4.2 started user /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist
```

But when I ty to connect to mongo shell, it gives

```
zsh: command not found: mongo
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
says macOS could prevent it from running so go to configure some security settings, but I don't see any security message in System Preference.

---

A Fix: I could run just manually typing the path, and configured the PATH.
Is there any way I can start mongo shell through Homebrew?